# How to get Webpack to build multiple configuration exports in serial rather than in parallel?

Tags: webpack

I am using [Webpack's multiple configuration export functionality](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) to build two separate sets of bundles. The second configuration here (labeled serviceWorkerConfig) requires a file emitted from the first configuration. I naively assumed they run in serial because it was an array, but I guess not.

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const bundleProcessor = require("./webpack.bundleProcessor.config.js")
const serviceWorkerConfig = require("./webpack.serviceWorker.config.js")

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return [
        merge(bundleProcessor,
            { mode: "development", }
        ),
        merge(serviceWorkerConfig, // requires file emitted from first configuration
            { mode: "development" }
        ),
    ];
};
```

I tried adding `module.exports.parallelism = 1;` as in the example given in the docs, but that doesn't appear to work for me.

Is there a way to get Webpack to build multiple configuration exports in serial rather than in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I did the similar thing by running Webpack serially by

1. similar with your Webpack config, but returns a dict like

```
{
   a: {configForA}, b: {configForB}
}
```

2. call webpack twice like

```
webpack NODE_ENV=a && webpack NODE_ENV=b
```

Though it's not some settings from Webpack, it worked. Not sure whether you tried it or if it suits.

Comment: This is similar to what we are currently doing. The first run creates JSON file with all the assets that I need to precache in the service worker, which is processed in the second run. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`parallelism` is the number of CPU to use (you'd need a single threaded CPU for this to work). While `maxConcurrentWorkers` sounds rather promising, but this is only available through the [NodeJS API](https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack#nodejs-api). Beside that [`webpack-chain`](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain) seems to be close to what you're asking for... let's face it, one cannot merge a single item (as shown in the example above - for comparison, the [docs](https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/composing-configuration/)).
And if it has to be merge, this should be a merged configuration, consisting of the configuration for that one file, to be merged with the `serviceWorkerConfig`, which depends on it.

I think that a plugin which merges configurations might not even fit the job.... but the one module has to depend on the other. When defined as `library` & [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/), this would rather represent the dependency, which apparently exists but never had been declared.

A simple script (as suggested by @Wenbo) might indeed be the least effort... and it could in between also check for / copy over the one file in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think monorepo and its app dependency will help in your situations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).